# Shortcuts in Wolfram Cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

When I use the cloud version of mathematica, the shortcuts like "cntrl /" and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NotebookShortcuts.html
  don't work.

I believe it is because the browser reads the shortcut, rather than the cloud software.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: You can't ovecome the fact that many tokens are not implemented (?yet). Only WRI can answer what is the plan.

Comment: Also your broswer and os settings would likely override them.

Comment: Has this still not changed?? At least it doesn't work for me, as of 2021...

Answer (score 2):

One option is using CNTRL $ or in fact, CNTRL 4 to get a TeX input box, and input a TeX or LaTeX command. You get out of the little TeX input box by pressing TAB.

This allows to do at least some of the things (but not fractions) that other CNTRL shortcuts allow you to do. This seems to be the only CNTRL shortcut that works, as far as I know, on my Macbook pro running Big Sur (11.5.2) as of Sep 2021.