# Input subscripts in Wolfram Cloud

Tags: syntax, wolfram-cloud, keyboard, subscript, parsing

I would like to input "rendered" subscripts in **Wolfram Cloud**, without having to verbosely type `Subscript[a, b]`. The local notebook shortcut is `ctrl` + `-`,
but as per [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191655/shortcuts-in-wolfram-cloud), such shortcuts are not yet available. One can copy the rendered output of evaluating `Subscript[a,b]` into another input line, so it is possible that the input form contains rendered subscripts, albeit as non-editable tokens.

I am wondering whether it's possible to define a set of input transformation rules to parse and modify input as it is typed. For example, so that custom syntax like `a((b))` would be immediately replaced with the output render of `Subscript[a,b]`. I note that I could do this *after* cell evaluationg using `CellEpilog`, as per [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194775/how-can-i-automatically-replace-and-with-the-leftdoublebracket-and-ri), but I wish to perform the substitution 'on-the-fly' while the input is typed.

Is this at all possible? I can naturally choose a 'to be replaced' syntax in lieu of `a((b))` which doesn't prematurely evaluate.

Comment: I don't use Wolfram Cloud but have you tried using `Format[a[b]] := Subscript[a, b]` or `Format[x[n_Integer]] := Subscript[x, n]` then input as indexed variables in subsequent code.

Comment: You can render TeX in Mathematica using Ctrl+Shift+4. For example, press Crtl-Shift+4 and then type a_b and then Enter to get the equivalent of Subscript[a,b].

Comment: @BobHanlon Nice idea (albeit not 'on-the-fly'), though among the symbols I need to format is `C`, and `Format[C[q_]] := Subscript[C, q]` throws an error (`Tag C is Protected`)

Comment: @MikeZ. Also a nice idea, and works in the Cloud,though I can't work out how to specify expressions like `Subscript[a, b][arg]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Note too the re-formatting seems to occur *after* the expression is evaluated. Hence, functions which expected subscripts and not `a[b]` won't evaluate.

Comment: One can just name variables. c1=Subscript[C,1] and then use c1. I also use things like alpha=ECS alpha ESC to save me some trouble when typing input... I have a long list of these assignments at the beginning of my nb. It's an ugly hack, but it does make the output prettier and inputting remains easy.